# Run startx in the background without switching to the new virtual terminal

Tags: terminal, console, x-server

`startx` is able to create a new X server in a new virtual terminal. However, even if I run it in the background, ie. `sudo startx &`, it still switches to the new virtual terminal automatically. Is it possible to create a new virtual terminal while still staying in the old one?

Also, how can I know the file name of the new terminal? (Previously, I can use `tty` to check in the new window, but how can I achieve the same thing in the old one?)

Comment: What you're calling “window” is in fact called “virtual console” or “virtual terminal” (“vt” for short). It doesn't make sense to me to call them “window”, even if I infer the meaning from context.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Gilles  Thanks for correcting me! Yes I indeed don't know how to call it. And I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using X.org, this doesn't seem to be possible. The X server supports an [option](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xorg.1.xhtml#heading7) called `-novtswitch` but that only applies when the X server exits, not when it starts. Given the discussion in [Fedora bug #246267](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=246267), it seems that this option also applied when starting, but this was removed because it caused the X server to crash on a lot of hardware: the X server needs to access the video hardware when it starts.

The next best thing would be to allow a short flicker to another vt and switch back. On Linux, you can use [`openvt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/openvt.1.html) to run a command in a new virtual terminal and [`chvt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chvt.1.html) to change back.

Create a script `~/.xinitrc.chvt` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "New X session running on vt$X_FGCONSOLE" >"$ORIGINAL_TTY"
chvt "$ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE"
exec ~/.xinitrc
```

and run

```
ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole) ORIGINAL_TTY=$(tty) openvt -s -- sh -c 'export X_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole); startx ~/.xinitrc.chvt -- vt$X_FGCONSOLE'
```

(The separate script `~/.xinitrc.chvt` as opposed to `sh -c …` is needed because `startx` messes up arguments containing wildcards, and you need to pass the absolute path due to another quirk of startx. Alternatively, call `xinit` directly and set up `XAUTHORITY` on your own.)

Depending on where you're running this script, you may not have the permission to run `fgconsole` (“Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console”), because it needs to be able to open `/dev/console` and it can't do that if some other user (root, in practice) owns it. I don't know how to find out how to return to the original console otherwise. One solution, if you have root access, would be to replace `ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole) …` by

```
ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(sudo fgconsole)
```

and give your account the permission to run `fgconsole` as root by running `visudo` and adding the line

```
zzy ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/fgconsole
```

after any other line that applies to your account. It's safe barring a bug in the `fgconsole` program.

¹  <sub>If you're using Linux you're using X.org, and if you aren't using Linux there's still a good change that you're using X.org.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the script! I acknowledge that I'm a newbie for xserver and couldn't understand it well. `$(fgconsole)` leads to "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console" on my machine. And besides this error msg, when I run the script following your guidance, I jumped to a new vt (the new term I learnt just now), and blocked forever at "waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file." I find that, I can use ctrl+alt+f7 to go back to the original vt, and ctrl+alt+f8 to go into this blocking vt. Is this expected?

Comment: I'm using the default Ubuntu 14.04 (I believe I didn't install a new xserver). As far as I'm concerned, it should be xorg (please correct me if I'm wrong here). Also, is it possible to get the file name of the new vt (the second part of my question)? I suspect `$(fgconsole)` may have sth to do with this.

Comment: @zzy `fgconsole` returns the number of the current console, but it doesn't always work when you're under X, only if you ran `startx` and told the X server to use the same console (or more generally a console that you were logged into), as opposed to telling the X server to use a new console or using an X display manager. I made a few tweaks to the script, in particular the message “New X session …” was going to a file instead of the original terminal, but if `fgconsole` doesn't work where you're starting, I don't know how to find out how to get back without running `fgconsole` as root.

Comment: Thank you! Yes `$(fgconsole)` works well with `sudo`. And I also add `sudo` for the one after `X_FGCONSOLE=` in your command. But the line adding to `/etc/sudoers` by `visudo` seems to be incorrect, the file will corrupt after adding this line (I have to revert it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi). Also, the new vt shows `.xinitrc` not found, which lies at the last line of your script. I double checked and I indeed don't have such file. Do I miss anything here?

Comment: @zzy `.xinitrc` is the file that runs your user session. If you don't have one and then the system file `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is used instead. For the sudoers line, I'd forgotten to put the absolute path, but if you use visudo then it detects syntax errors and refuses to change the configuration, no recovery is needed.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the line with absolute path works for `visudo` now. I'm sorry to edit `/etc/sudoers` directly before, which forces me to fix it afterwards. Now I changed the last line of the script to `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` and run `ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole) ORIGINAL_TTY=$(tty) openvt -s -- sh -c 'export X_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole); startx ~/.xinitrc.chvt -- vt$X_FGCONSOLE'`.

Comment: (cont.) I didn't see error message anymore but the new vt is still blocked at "waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file." after numerous "Initializing built-in extension xxx" and "Loading extension GLX". Do you have any insights for this?

Comment: @zzy Is an X session started on a different vt? The behavior you describe is normal when the X server is running on a different vt from startx. Please replace `sh -c …` by `sh -xc 2>$(tty) …`, this should print a few lines of traces on the original terminal, let me know what they are.

Comment: I tried but didn't get any output in the original terminal. Both `ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole) ORIGINAL_TTY=$(tty) openvt -s -- sh -xc 2>$(tty) 'export X_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole); startx ~/.xinitrc.chvt -- vt$X_FGCONSOLE'` and `ORIGINAL_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole) ORIGINAL_TTY=$(tty) openvt -s -- sh -xc 'export X_FGCONSOLE=$(fgconsole); startx ~/.xinitrc.chvt -- vt$X_FGCONSOLE' 2>$(tty)`. Do I miss anything here?