# How to prevent switching to a different tty when Xserver starts?

Tags: tty, x-server

I am working with tty2 because Linux terminates all processes every 30 seconds and Xserver refuses to start.

How can I keep tty2 in the foreground while the Xserver can go crazy in background?

Comment: Have you tried screen or does that get terminated too.

Comment: It's your question, but IMHO I'd address the X Server issue as opposed to trying to "keep tty2 in the foreground".

Comment: a) if you want to stop the broken Xserver from trying to start: `service gdm stop` (replace `gdm` with `lightdm`, `xdm` or whatever you're using). b) if you want to debug the broken Xserver -- login from another machine via ssh or serial. c) if you want to start the Xserver on another virtual terminal without switching to it, then your question is a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319980/run-startx-in-the-background-without-switching-to-the-new-virtual-terminal) (and I don't have a good answer to it, either).

Comment: @dirkt it appears to me that n.st only rephrased the title; the "30 seconds" information was posted by nevermind9.